# DB Storage vs DB CPU - Storing calculated data or calculating with a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, database-schema, database-performance

As I am considering a new table design for a database of mine. I am torn between storing final calculations in a table column, or calculating them in the View that I plan to create.  For example, if you were to store the value 10 in one column, and 5 in another, and you wanted to get (10/5) in another, is it better in your opinion to store the 5 in its own column, or calculate it in the planned View?

The table will contain about 400k records a day for maybe a year or so.  Even though I can use simple datatypes to reduce storage costs, I still then have to maintain another 4 bytes of data per record * how ever many calculated records in that same row I may have.

I will be querying against the calculated values, over several days of data.  I still want speed, but also want a smaller database, easier to maintain tables, and the flexibility of a view.

What are your views and thoughts?

Comment: Out of "take two - fast, good, cheap" you seem to want all 3... Your amount of data seem to be large enough so trying and measuring both cases should easily pay off in a long run...

Comment: Yea, I am going to do some tests on both, just curious what everyone else might find most important.

Answer (score 2):

> I will be querying against the calculated values...

I what way?

- If the calculated value is just mentioned in the SELECT list, then don't store it.<sup>1</sup>
- If it's in WHERE, you'd want to index it, in which case most DBMSes will force you to persist it in one way or another.<sup>2</sup>

---

*<sup>1</sup> For a small increase in CPU, you'll reduce the storage requirements and therefore increase the cache effectiveness and therefore decrease the I/O, which tends to be the most important performance bottleneck in most OLTP workloads. Caching the result is justified when the calculation is expensive, but a simple division is very far from that threshold.*

*<sup>2</sup> Either in the table as a normal field, or as a persisted computed column or in a materialized/indexed view.*

Answer (score 1):

Data integrity is most important.

Computing a result in a view is guaranteed to give you the most up-do-date answer. The trade-off is run-time performance for SELECT statements, especially if the result is used in a WHERE clause. In my experience, the result of computation is rarely if ever used in a WHERE clause. And by *computation*, I mean not only arithmetic, but string and substring extraction and concatenation, checksum computation, etc.

Storing the result of a calculation in a base table gives you the best SELECT performance. The trade-off is data integrity. If you can write a CHECK() constraint that guarantees the result is always right, you should do that. But CHECK() constraints for complex computations are sometimes impossible to express without using a user-defined function, and not all platforms support user-defined functions in CHECK() constraints.

If you can't write a CHECK() constraint, you still need *some* kind of procedure to periodically check your data for errors. In the worst case, you can run a report daily or weekly during low demand.

A materialized view might give you the best of both worlds--a computation that can be the target of a sargable WHERE clause, and that is always guaranteed to be right. (The SQL Server equivalent is called an *indexed view*.) The trade-off is storage space and the CPU cycles needed to keep the materialized view and its indexes up to date following updates to the base tables.

Ordinarily, I'd try a view first. But in your particular case--400k rows per day for 365 days--I think I'd try a materialized view first. It that doesn't work well for whatever reason, you can replace it with a column in the base table, drop the materialized view, and create a new view having the same name. (Logical data independence rocks.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dev environment, I would suggest testing both methods and choosing the one that offers the best performance per work/maintenance cost. Even if the table is storing ~400k records, depending on how you are accessing that data, one method may make more sense.